# Playing .m3u8 audio stream file through monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, audio-streaming

I am currently developing an iPhone app that streams audio. The URL I wish to stream is an m3u8 file at the following link:

http://216.246.37.52:1935/highveld/highveld.stream/playlist.m3u8

I can load the NSRequest on a webview which will open the stream but this pushes my application to the background when it opens the stream and the only way to get back to the app is to close the stream.

I would prefer a play button on my view which will start playing the stream when it is clicked and the user should be able to switch tabs within the application without stopping the stream.

In essence, the stream should continue playing until the user deliberately stops it. If somebody can give me any idea as to how to do this within MonoTouch and C# for an iPhone application or point me to a tutorial, that would be great. I have scoured Google but with no avail.

Comment: Your confusion is thinking that a `.m3u8` file has anything to do with a stream.  The `.m3u8` file is nothing but a playlist.  What you need to be searching for is streaming over HTTP, probably in MP3 but I don't know for sure, since the link in the playlist is broken.

Comment: Thanks for this @Brad. I have opened the playlist in notepad and all I get inside of it is this:


_#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=250000
http://216.246.37.52:1935/jacaranda-bkp/JacarandaFM-Powered_by_Antfarm.stream/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=963158135_

I am not sure what to do with this, however, should you take the link stated in the post and enter it into an iPhone in safari, the link opens and the stream starts to play. Any comments on this?

Comment: Yes, that's what is supposed to happen.  Again, the M3U is just a playlist file, and in it is the URL(s) of the media.  If you open the URL directly, you're opening the media directly.  What's happening in your case, is that the browser sees the `Content-Type` header as something its media player can deal with, so it starts playing it.

Comment: @Brad, If the media player sees the stream as Something it can deal with, would it not work by using the media player in monotouch?  
using MonoTouch.MediaPlayer;  
Example:  
var moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (new NSUrl ("http://216.246.37.52:1935/highveld/highveld.stream/playlist.m3u8"));  
moviePlayer.Play ();  

I have tried this and the stream does not start playing when I do this. It just kind of sits there. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I should use the stream url within the playlist file when using this method?  

I have updated the stream in the post to a working one.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers Thanks for your input. This is my current solution for this. If all else fails I will have to make do with this. The problem with this solution is that when the stream opens it pushes the app to the background which I do not want.

Comment: @Brad, I have updated the stream link above to one that works.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain to you that you that your link to a `.m3u8` file is **just a playlist, does not contain audio data, and doesn't have to have anything to do with streaming**.  It is just a pointer to where the actual stream is.  You need to **parse the playlist**, and then **stream data from the URLs within**.

Comment: @Brad, i completely understand that. That is why I am asking if the media player as in my comment above will be able to use that playlist "which does mot contain the stream or any audio data" to actually point the media player to the stream? Is that not the same process that happens when the playlist file url is entered into safari directly because when you enter the playlist file url into safari, the playlist then directs the media player to the actual stream and starts playing. Am i correct by assuming this?

Comment: No, that is different.  What you need to do in your application is parse the playlist file, and then pass the stream URL to the media player for playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joachim. I have also build a streaming solution and accomplished this in a different way. With a bit of poking around I found the actual Shoutcast stream at http://216.246.37.52:8028/. Not sure if this will help you in your situation. Perhaps you can generate your own playlist. Good luck!. Riaan

Comment: Thanks for this. how did you manage to find the port number for the stream? How did you accomplish this in your streaming app? can you maybe supply me with the app name so I can check it out? Thanks